# Modules with meta box implementations

Tags: metabox

I am looking for some modules that implement add meta box as shown [here](http://wefunction.com/2008/10/tutorial-creating-custom-write-panels-in-wordpress/) perhaps with some ajax magic.

If you have any modules I could check out would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently published a meta box class named [**`My Meta Box`**](https://github.com/bainternet/My-Meta-Box) which takes care of most of the metabox creation and data saving and that was forked out of from Meta Box script by Rilwis.

Using the class is simple eg:

```
<?php

require_once("meta-box-class/my-meta-box-class.php");
if (is_admin()){
/*
* prefix of meta keys, optional
* use underscore (_) at the beginning to make keys hidden, for example $prefix = '_ba_';
* you also can make prefix empty to disable it
*
*/
$prefix = 'ba_';
/*
* configure your meta box
*/
$config = array(
'id' => 'demo_meta_box', // meta box id, unique per meta box
'title' => 'Demo Meta Box', // meta box title
'pages' => array('post', 'page'), // post types, accept custom post types as well, default is array('post'); optional
'context' => 'normal', // where the meta box appear: normal (default), advanced, side; optional
'priority' => 'high', // order of meta box: high (default), low; optional
'fields' => array(), // list of meta fields (can be added by field arrays)
'local_images' => false // Use local or hosted images (meta box images for add/remove)
);
/*
* Initiate your meta box
*/
$my_meta = new AT_Meta_Box($config);

/*
* Add fields to your meta box
*/

//text field
$my_meta->addTextField($prefix.'text_field_id',array('name'=> 'My Text Field'));
//textarea field
$my_meta->addTextareaField($prefix.'textarea_field_id',array('name'=> 'My Textarea Field'));
//checkbox field
$my_meta->addCheckboxField($prefix.'checkbox_field_id',array('name'=> 'My Checkbox Field'));
//select field
$my_meta->addSelectField($prefix.'select_field_id',array('selectkey1'=>'Select Value1','selectkey2'=>'Select Value2'),array('name'=> 'My select Field', 'std'=> array('selectkey2')));
//checkboxList
$my_meta->addCheckboxListField($prefix.'ch_list_field_id',array('selectkey1'=>'Select Value1','selectkey2'=>'Select Value2'),array('name'=> 'My CheckBox List Field', 'std'=> array('selectkey2')));
//radio field
$my_meta->addRadioField($prefix.'radio_field_id',array('radiokey1'=>'Radio Value1','radiokey2'=>'Radio Value2'),array('name'=> 'My Radio Filed', 'std'=> array('radionkey2')));
//date field
$my_meta->addDateField($prefix.'date_field_id',array('name'=> 'My Date Field'));
//Time field
$my_meta->addTimeField($prefix.'time_field_id',array('name'=> 'My Time Field'));
//Color field
$my_meta->addColorField($prefix.'color_field_id',array('name'=> 'My Color Field'));
//Image field
$my_meta->addImageField($prefix.'image_field_id',array('name'=> 'My Image Field'));
//file upload field
$my_meta->addFileField($prefix.'file_field_id',array('name'=> 'My File Field'));
//wysiwyg field
$my_meta->addWysiwygField($prefix.'wysiwyg_field_id',array('name'=> 'My wysiwyg Editor Field'));
//taxonomy field
$my_meta->addTaxonomyField($prefix.'taxonomy_field_id',array('taxonomy' => 'category'),array('name'=> 'My Taxonomy Field'));
//posts field
$my_meta->addPostsField($prefix.'posts_field_id',array('post_type' => 'post'),array('name'=> 'My Posts Field'));

/*
* To Create a reapeater Block first create an array of fields
* use the same functions as above but add true as a last param
*/

$repeater_fields[] = $my_meta->addTextField($prefix.'text_field_id',array('name'=> 'My Text Field'),true);
$repeater_fields[] = $my_meta->addTextareaField($prefix.'textarea_field_id',array('name'=> 'My Textarea Field'),true);
$repeater_fields[] = $my_meta->addCheckboxField($prefix.'checkbox_field_id',array('name'=> 'My Checkbox Field'),true);

/*
* Then just add the fields to the repeater block
*/
//repeater block
$my_meta->addRepeaterBlock($prefix.'text_field_id',array('inline' => true, 'name' => 'This is a Repeater Block','fields' => $repeater_fields));
/*
* Don't Forget to Close up the meta box decleration
*/
//Finish Meta Box Decleration
$my_meta->Finish();
}
```

Take a look at the `class-usage-demo.php` file which can also be tested as a WordPress Plugin. Other options are available for each field which can be see in the 'my-meta-box-class.php' file.

And also you can see it in use in my latest plugin [ShortCodes UI](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/shortcodes-ui/)

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for. One question, how would I add a simple button with some javascript / jquery to a metabox via the api? I notice the examples all contain some kind of input field, but in my case I just want a simple button with jquery ajax that grabs the post content and posts it remotely to a service, and the box will show the result.

Comment: you have a function named `addParagraph` which you can use to add anytime you want (html buttons,js code). just make sure you have the latest version of the metabox class 0.1.4

Comment: Why fork? Rilwis classes are nice already.

Comment: @Kaiser i never said anything bad about his classes i just needed so extra functionality that was missing and that is done by forking.

Comment: At some point you may find yourself wanting to contribute to someone else’s project, or would like to use someone’s project as the starting point for your own. This is known as “forking.”

Comment: I guess you got it into the wrong throat. I just wanted to know the _why_. Nothing else. Furthermore: Did you make pull requests and are they going to get in?

Comment: @bainternet After looking at rilwis repository, I guess I have to redraw my words. The group of people who actually _forked_ it, don't hold your name. You downloaded, modified and uploaded it again. Not that this is against the license. I just can't see anything good in the way you did it. Rilwis offered it on github for collaboration, in other words: to make it better for all. Where's the point in making a separate repo and running two parallel versions, slowely moving apart? Why don't you simply made pull requests?

Comment: @Bainternet: Hi, I found that your class adds nice additions to the original class. I think it's useful. Would you want to [fork me on GitHub](https://github.com/rilwis/meta-box) and collaborate what you've done here? BTW, the script is now available on [WP.org](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/meta-box/) as a plugin, too.

Comment: kaiser: _forked_ doesn't necessarily mean that it was forked on github, it simply means that its _based on_, and the only reason is I didn't know rilwis had a github repo for it (which is relatively new).

Comment: @rilwis: I'd be happy to do that, as soon as i get a chance :)

Comment: @Bainternet Already saw your fork added. I forked it too, now hoping that the result will make meta box world a little better :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking here, but the most basic example you can get here, along with everything else there is to know about `add_meta_box`, complete with save code and security checks:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box

```
<?php
/* Define the custom box */
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'myplugin_add_custom_box' );


/* Do something with the data entered */
add_action( 'save_post', 'myplugin_save_postdata' );

/* Adds a box to the main column on the Post and Page edit screens */
function myplugin_add_custom_box() {
    add_meta_box( 
        'myplugin_sectionid',
        __( 'My Post Section Title', 'myplugin_textdomain' ),
        'myplugin_inner_custom_box',
        'post' 
    );
}

/* Prints the box content */
function myplugin_inner_custom_box( $post ) {

  // Use nonce for verification
  wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'myplugin_noncename' );

  // The actual fields for data entry
  echo '<label for="myplugin_new_field">';
       _e("Description for this field", 'myplugin_textdomain' );
  echo '</label> ';
  echo '<input type="text" id="myplugin_new_field" name="myplugin_new_field" value="whatever" size="25" />';
}

/* When the post is saved, saves our custom data */
function myplugin_save_postdata( $post_id ) {
  // verify if this is an auto save routine. 
  // If it is our form has not been submitted, so we dont want to do anything
  if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
      return;

  // verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
  // because save_post can be triggered at other times

  if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['myplugin_noncename'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
      return;


  // Check permissions
  if ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) 
  {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) )
        return;
  }
  else
  {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
        return;
  }

  // OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data

  $mydata = $_POST['myplugin_new_field'];

  // Do something with $mydata 
  // probably using add_post_meta(), update_post_meta(), or 
  // a custom table (see Further Reading section below)
}
?>
```